# Pandas Multilevel index for rows

Tags: pandas, multi-index

This should be a simple thing, but after a few hours of searching, I'm still at a loss for what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried different methods using MultiIndexing.from_ and multiple other things, but I just can't get this right.

I need something like:
[image]


But instead I get:
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_customers = ['Client1', 'Client2', 'Client3']
stat_index = ['max', 'current', 'min']
list_of_historic_timeframes = ['16:10', '16:20', '16:30']

timeblock = pd.DataFrame(index=([list_of_customers, stat_index]), columns=list_of_historic_timeframes)
timeblock.fillna(0, inplace=True)

print(timeblock)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list_of_customers = ['Client1', 'Client2', 'Client3']
stat_index = ['max', 'current', 'min']
list_of_historic_timeframes = ['16:10', '16:20', '16:30']


timeblock = pd.DataFrame(
    0,
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [list_of_customers, stat_index],
        names=['Customer', 'Stat']
    ),
    list_of_historic_timeframes
)

print(timeblock)

                  16:10  16:20  16:30
Customer Stat                        
Client1  max          0      0      0
         current      0      0      0
         min          0      0      0
Client2  max          0      0      0
         current      0      0      0
         min          0      0      0
Client3  max          0      0      0
         current      0      0      0
         min          0      0      0
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much.
Even after looking at multiple examples, I was using the MultiIndex incorrectly and using the wrong from_.

Comment: Now I'm stuck on updating specific values.
I know how to work with multidimensional Numpy arrays, but for some reason I'm not addressing these correctly.

I can update a whole row, but I'm not able to specify a column correctly.

Comment: `timeblock.loc[('Client1', 'min'), '16:20'] = 3`

Comment: Thanks again.  I was close, but didn't quite have it right.  
  
This works great in the sample code, but adds a new column in my real data.  I think it has to do with the original column headers being in datetime format and the addition being a string, but I can work around that.  

Thanks again!  Great help.